# Error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure... in python

Tags: python, django

**What I want to do:** I'm trying to run tests with unittest for functions in my views.

**Outcome**: I'm getting the following error:

*....env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 189, in _fetch
    "The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the "
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time.*

**Imports used:**

```
import unittest
from django.test import Client
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
import sys
sys.path.append('../../mysite/')
from mysite.settings import *
from views import *
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

As you can see I tried this answer with no success: [appregistrynotready-the-translation-infrastructure-cannot-be-initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630155/appregistrynotready-the-translation-infrastructure-cannot-be-initialized)

I followed this one too: [upgrading-to-django-1-7-getting-appregistrynotready-for-translation-infrastruct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675593/upgrading-to-django-1-7-getting-appregistrynotready-for-translation-infrastruct)

**Imports I found with ugettext & ugettext_lazy:**

```
from django.utils.translation import ungettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.translation import ungettext, ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

I changed them to

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

But it didn't work either

**Some code I found with ugettext**

```
return ugettext('%(number)d %(type)s') % {'number': delta.seconds, 100  'type': count(delta.seconds)}
```

I was wondering if there could be a problem with this.

I found it worked if I removed this lines from authentication/models.py:

```
last_pass_change = models.DateTimeField(_("last_pass_change"), default=datetime.datetime.now())
last_failed_login = models.DateTimeField(_("last_failed_login"), default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

But I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Why are you not using the [existing test infrastructure](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/), which also provides you with a [dummy client for testing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#test-client)?

Comment: `default=datetime.datetime.now()` <= This sets the default value to the date and time when `models.py` is loaded. You probably wanted to omit the brackets. And you also might want to read about [timezones and datetimes in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it changing:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

to:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the WSGI application before you import from views and settings.

```
application = get_wsgi_application()    
from mysite.settings import *
from views import *
```